# Exception while using PowerMockito with static method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

I want to mock a static method using PowerMockito,

```
public class DepedencyService {

    public static int getImportantValue() {
        return -4;
    }
}

public class Component {

    public int componentMethod() {
        return DepedencyService.getImportantValue();
    }
}
```

but it is giving me an exception.

```
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(DepedencyService.class)
public class ComponentTest {
    @Test
    public void testComponentMethod() {
        Component c = new Component();
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(DepedencyService.class);
        EasyMock.expect(DepedencyService.getImportantValue()).andReturn(1);
        assertEquals(1, c.componentMethod());
    }
}
```

The exception :-

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available     at
>   org.easymock.EasyMock.getControlForLastCall(EasyMock.java:520)    at
>   org.easymock.EasyMock.expect(EasyMock.java:498)

Can anyone please help me? Why is this failing? I am new to PowerMockito and does not know what to do here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be mixing mocking frameworks.

You need to properly arrange the static dependencies before exercising the test

Since PowerMockito is used to mock the static class then you should use Mockito to arrange the expected behavior

For example

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(DepedencyService.class)
public class ComponentTest {
    @Test
    public void testComponentMethod() {
        //Arrange        
        int expected = 1;
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(DepedencyService.class);
        Mockito.when(DepedencyService.getImportantValue()).thenReturn(expected);
        Component subject = new Component();

        //Act
        int actual = subject.componentMethod();

        //Assert
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

That said, I would advise not having your code tightly coupled to static dependencies. It makes for difficult to test code.

Comment: I understand that but it is a utility class so i have made the methods inside it as static.

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is that you're writing [STUPID code](https://williamdurand.fr/2013/07/30/from-stupid-to-solid-code/) (like most of us did at the beginning) where you rather should write SOLID code.

Using <strike>Powermock</strike> is just a surrender to this bad design.

Yes, classes having only  `static` methods are called *utility classes*.

But you should get over this misconception that classes providing common behavior should have (only) `static` methods.

As a rule of thumb there should be only one *non private* `static` method in your entire program, and this is `main()`.

Comment: @Sunny at least you could write a simple (= too simple to fail = no tests needed) WrapperClass  around this legacy code and use that wrapper with your new code to test.

Comment: Okie that is something that i can do. but i have seen utility classes such as IOUtils.java ... so if what u are saying is the ultimate truth then why did the developers created such classes?

Comment: @Sunny *"so if what u are saying is the ultimate truth then why did the developers created such classes?"* developers are humans and like all other humans they do dumb things for many reasons. And since I'm a human too I do not hold "the ultimate truth", I just share what made my developers life easier.